# Erlang string:join vs io_lib:format

Tags: erlang

I have a bit of code where I am taking 4 values and joining them with a pipe ("|"). currently it is implemented in the following manner:

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~s~s~s~s~s",[Id, Delim, Date, Delim, Signature])).
```

But, I'm wondering if there is any advantage to changing to use string:join (other than it appears cleaner)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `string:join([Id,Date,Signature],"|").` and `lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~s~s~s~s~s",[Id, Delim, Date, Delim, Signature])).` give the same result, `string:join` is preferred, because has better readability:

- The name of the function describes the actual intent.
- It's concise, so the reader is less distracted by verbosity.

Readability is paramount, as code is often read many, many times during a project

Answer (score 2):

It would be marginally faster but more importantly easier to read, and as I always claim "Clarity is king."

Answer (score 1):

Just using

```
 [Id, $|, Delim,
      $|, Date,
      $|, Delim,
      $|, Signature]
```

could be valid since it is an `iolist()` already. So you don't have to send it through anything. The data *is* already the concatenation you seek. Manipulating the data and flattening it for the sake of doing so is most often a mistake which at best wastes clock cycles and uses more memory resources.